# Show number of observations in R Scatter plot with factor levels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My Data Frame `d`

```
str(d)
'data.frame':   10821 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Actual : Factor w/ 10 levels "SA103","SA111",..: 6 6 6 6 9 9 6 9 6 6 ...
 $ Planned: Factor w/ 17 levels "SA103","SA111",..: 1 6 6 6 1 9 6 9 6 6 ...
```

I am plotting this using **ggplot2** with following code

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=Actual, y=Planned))   + geom_point()
```

[image: Plot Result]

I want to show number of observations at each point to easily identify where the deviation is large between Planned & Actual levels. (Example: if it shows SA121 (planned) moved to SA103 (Actual) ~1000 times then it is a serious concern.

**How to put data labels in this type of plot with data labels showing number of observations (for given x,y condition)?**

Comment: Thanks for Edit & Image Link :)

Comment: do you want labels? hexplot might be a good alternative.

Comment: @Anata: "hexplot" ? Is it package or ggplot2 option ? Google did not turn up anything in this case !

Comment: `g+geom_hex() `(requires, `hexbin` package)

Comment: @Ananta: Thanks, I will look into that also along with `geom_count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to see the number of obs at each point, you could create your own function to extract N, and then call that function in stat_summary within ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
Actual <- sample( LETTERS[1:10], 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(rep(0.25, 10)))
Planned <- sample( LETTERS[1:17], 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(rep(0.25, 17) ))
d <-as.data.frame(cbind(Actual, Planned))

N <- function(x){
  return(data.frame(y = mean(x), label = length(x)))
 }

  ggplot(d, aes(x=Actual, y=Planned))   +stat_summary(fun.data = N, geom =  "text")
```

[image]
  Alternatively, you can use geom_count() to size your points by the number of observations.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Actual, y=Planned))  + geom_point() + geom_count()
```

[image]

Comment: seems `geom_count()` is new feature

Comment: @Wyldsoul: `geom_count()` not available in my version. Update is in progress :) I will confirm after that. Thanks

Comment: stat_sum() does essentially the same thing, and may be available in an earlier version

Comment: @Wyldsoul: Thanks, I ended up using `stat_summary` after some cleanup for my requirement :)